# Crystal Reports - Checking for a row in a table based on criteria from two different columns

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table of jobs, with columns showing which engineer the job is assigned to and the area of the country, which can be simplified like this:

```
JobNumber Area  Engineer
   1        A      3
   2        D      1
   3        E      2
   4        B      2
   5        A      1
```

I have a table of engineers, and a table of areas of the country.

I have a final table which shows the areas of the country each engineer is assigned to, like this:

```
Area  Engineer
A      1
A      2
A      3
B      2
B      3
```

What I need to do in Crystal Reports, is create a formula field (or similar) to show whether or not the engineer was in one of his assigned areas.

I think the reason my efforts thus far have failed is that the join is effectively circular. I have played around with SQL Commands and join options to no avail.

Can anybody offer advice on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried joining engineer field?

Comment: This statement is not clear "to show whether or not the engineer was in one of his assigned areas"?

Comment: Siva, I am already joining the engineer table to the jobs table, I could join again using an alias but I'd still be on the same position.

Comment: Pinwar, the pseudo logic for what I'm trying to do is this:  if (engineers inner join engineersareas inner join areas) returns a row using the engineer and area combination in a given job, return 'yes' else 'no'

Comment: For anyone out there in a similar position, I have not been able to solve this using only Crystal - instead I have solved by creating a View on the SQL server - jobs inner join engineers inner join engineersareas, then left join to areas, case when areas.name is not null then yes else no